# Querying one column by max value on another column after groupBy

Tags: pyspark

```
+-------+--------------------+-------+
|  brand|       category_code|  count|
+-------+--------------------+-------+
|samsung|electronics.smart...|1782386|
|  apple|electronics.smart...|1649525|
| xiaomi|electronics.smart...| 924383|
| huawei|electronics.smart...| 477946|
|   oppo|electronics.smart...| 242022|
|samsung|electronics.video.tv| 183988|
|  apple|electronics.audio...| 165277|
|   acer|  computers.notebook| 154599|
|  casio|  electronics.clocks| 141403|
```

I want to select a value from the column `brand` corresponding to the max value of column `count` after performing a groupBy on column `category_code`. So in the first row for the group `electronics.smartphone` in column `category_code` I want string `samsung` from column `brand` because it has the highest value in the count column...

Comment: what have you tried so far? please also show the expected output, not only the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First groupBy to identify rows with the largest count for each category_code, then join with the original dataframe to retrieve brand value corresponding to max count:

```
df1 =  df.groupBy("category_code").agg(F.max("count").alias("count"))
                    
df2 = df.join(df1, ["count", "category_code"]).drop("count")
```

this will produce df2 as follows

```
category_code          brand
---------------------------
electronics.smart...   samsung
electronics.video.tv   samsung
electronics.audio      apple
computers.notebook     acer
electronics.clocks     casio
```

Comment: Thanks Anna! That worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function like

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window=Window.partitionBy('category_code').orderBy(col('count').desc())

df = df.withColumn('row_number', row_number().over(window))\
     .filter(col('row_number')==1).drop('row_number')
```

This way you will have all the columns. later you can select only required columns.